# How to get full class path on file system for resolved ModuleID in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt, dependency-management

How to corellate artifact from libraryDependencies to its resolved classpath in dependencyClasspath?

**UPD**

Clarify question: How to get full class path on file system for resolved ModuleID?

Example:

I have ModuleID: `"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-servlets" % V.jetty`

And I want to knpw that classpath is: `C:\Users\user\.ivy2\cache\org.eclipse.jetty\jetty-servlets\jars\jetty-servlets-8.1.8.v20121106.jar`

Comment: Can you expand the question? I don't understand what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: @AlexSiman is my answer describing what you've tried to do?

Comment: @lpiepiora thank you for answer, it looks like what I need, however I had no chance to check your solution yet. I'll give you a feedback as soon as I check it in practice

Answer (score 3):

You can add a task to your `build.sbt` and then call it with `printDependencyClasspath`

```
val printDependencyClasspath = taskKey[Unit]("Prints location of the dependencies")

printDependencyClasspath := {
  val cp = (dependencyClasspath in Compile).value
  cp.foreach(f => println(s"${f.metadata.get(moduleID.key)} => ${f.data}"))
}
```