# Find list of dependency JARs in sbt

Tags: dependencies, sbt

How can I find a list of dependency JARs (e.g. `~/.ivy2/some/path/someName.jar`) from inside `build.sbt`?

I have tried `libraryDependencies.in(mySubproject).value`, but this gives only a list of triples, not full path names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try command `sbt "show mySubproject/dependencyClasspath"` it will show full classpath for the `mySubproject` project.

You could iterate over the list as mentioned in [How to get full class path on file system for resolved ModuleID in SBT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375298/how-to-get-full-class-path-on-file-system-for-resolved-moduleid-in-sbt)

Comment: I wanted to do it programmatically ("from inside build.sbt"), so the correct answer for me is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375298/how-to-get-full-class-path-on-file-system-for-resolved-moduleid-in-sbt